RC4 windows api decryption function works in c++ but not in golang
I am using the windows api SystemFunction033 from advapi32.dll to do RC4 decryption/encryption. My problem is, i want to port my working c++ code to golang, but the golang code does not work. I dont get the right result and i think, i maybe wrongly use the unsafe.Pointers.
On the c++ code it will succesfully decrypt the RC4 encrypted word "Hello", but on golang not:


C++
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// https://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d13/sysfunc_8c_source.html
// Function prototype for SystemFunction033
typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* _SystemFunction033)(
    struct ustring* memoryRegion,
    struct ustring* keyPointer);

struct ustring {
    DWORD Length;
    DWORD MaximumLength;
    PVOID Buffer;
} _data, key;

void printResult(const unsigned char* input, size_t size) {
    // Iterate over each byte in the input array
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Print each byte in hexadecimal format
        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(input[i]) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
   // Load the library
    HMODULE hAdvapi32 = LoadLibraryA("advapi32.dll");
    if (hAdvapi32 == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load advapi32.dll" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the address of the function
    _SystemFunction033 SystemFunction033 = (_SystemFunction033)GetProcAddress(hAdvapi32, "SystemFunction033");
    if (SystemFunction033 == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get the address of SystemFunction033" << std::endl;
        FreeLibrary(hAdvapi32);
        return 1;
    }

    // Print the address
    std::cout << "Address of SystemFunction033: " << std::hex << (void*)SystemFunction033 << std::endl;

    char _key[] = "supersecretkey";

    // Hello
    // unsigned char input[] = { 0x48,0x65,0x6c,0x6c,0x6f };
    // Hello but already RC4 Encrypted with key "supersecretkey"
    unsigned char input[] = { 0xc6,0x22,0xb5,0x00,0x3a };

    unsigned int input_size = sizeof(input);

    int sizer = sizeof(input) / sizeof(input[0]); // Calculate the size of the array
    // Convert each byte to its ASCII character equivalent and concatenate them
    std::string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizer; i++) {
        str += input[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Encrypted: " << str << std::endl;

    //Setting key values
    key.Buffer = (&_key);
    key.Length = sizeof(_key);

    //Setting input in the struct for Systemfunction033
    _data.Buffer = input;
    _data.Length = input_size;

    //Calling Systemfunction033
    SystemFunction033(&_data, &key);

    // Print the result in the desired format
    std::cout << "Result:" << std::endl;
    printResult(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(_data.Buffer), _data.Length);

    unsigned char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(_data.Buffer);
    int sizex = sizeof(input) / sizeof(input[0]); // Calculate the size of the array
    // Convert each byte to its ASCII character equivalent and concatenate them
    std::string strx;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizex; i++) {
        strx += ptr[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Decrypted: " << strx << std::endl;
}

Golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

type ustring struct {
    Length        uint32
    MaximumLength uint32
    Buffer        unsafe.Pointer
}

var (
    _data ustring
    key   ustring
)

func printResult(input []byte) {
    // Iterate over each byte in the input slice
    for _, b := range input {
        // Print each byte in hexadecimal format with '0x' prefix
        fmt.Printf("0x%02x\n", b)
    }
}

func main() {
    systemfunction033 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("advapi32.dll").NewProc("SystemFunction033")
    fmt.Printf("Address of SystemFunction033: %x\n", systemfunction033.Addr());

    // Define the key
    _key := []byte("supersecretkey")

    // Hello
    // input := []byte{0x48,0x65,0x6c,0x6c,0x6f}
    // Hello but already RC4 Encrypted with key "supersecretkey"
    input := []byte{0xc6,0x22,0xb5,0x00,0x3a}

    input_size := len(input)

    // Convert each byte to its ASCII character equivalent and concatenate them
    var str string
    for _, b := range input {
        str += string(b)
    }
    fmt.Println("Encrypted:", str)

    // Set key values
    key.Buffer = unsafe.Pointer(&_key[0])
    key.Length = uint32(len(_key))

    // Set input values
    _data.Buffer = unsafe.Pointer(&input[0])
    _data.Length = uint32(input_size)

    // Call the function
    _, _, _ = systemfunction033.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&_data)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&key)),
    )

    // Print the results
    // fmt.Printf("Call Result: %v, %v, %v\n", r1, r2, err)

    // unsafe.Pointer to []byte
    dataBytes := unsafe.Slice((*byte)(_data.Buffer), input_size)
    printResult(dataBytes)

    // Convert each byte to its ASCII character equivalent and concatenate them
    var strx string
    for _, b := range dataBytes {
        strx += string(b)
    }
    fmt.Println("Decrypted:", strx)
}


Shouldn't your encrypted strings look the same in the console? Incidentally, the RC4 algorithm isn't terribly complex, so you might consider rolling your own implementation instead of calling out to an external, undocumented API function.

Why not use CNG instead?

The bug is in the C code. Because of key.Length = sizeof(_key) the terminating 0x00 is taken into account and is included in the key. To prevent this, the length can be determined with key.Length = strlen(_key).
With this key size, the C code returns the ciphertext 0x91501dc584 for the plaintext Hello. This is also the expected value for the sample data used, see CyberChef.
If the ciphertext 0x91501dc584 is now used in the Go code, decryption is successful and the original plaintext Hello is returned.
Alternatively, the old ciphertext 0xc622b5003a can be decrypted in the Go code with the key _key := []byte("supersecretkey\x00") to the original plaintext Hello.
